# Spring JPA AuditorAware is empty for nested call in service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'am using `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)` in Spring Boot JPA application and having some issue with inserting entity. I created `@RestController` for REST API, `@Service` for extra business logic and spring's `JpaRepository` interfaces to access DB.

So the issue is when I want to update some entity and create some another entity in `@Service` (BL layer). When creating new entity from service I get exception that attribute annotated with `@CreatedBy` could not be null. I see that `AuditorAware` is empty. But if comment out creating of new entity and make update of first entity only then `AuditorAware` is not null and works fine.

It's also working if I create this problematic entity form `@Controller`.

Does anyone have similar problem and know how to solve this.

I suppose the proxyMode of AuditorAware `@Bean` is wrong but I don't know how to fixed it.

Comment: Issue is actually in tests. I'am using random-beans library to populate entity and if I create entity inside of service then random-beans not generate values created_by and so on. It is obviously that AuditorAware is null or actually SpringSecurity context is null but there were no exception because random-beans populate created_by values.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the implementation of `AuditorAware` from:

```
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return () -> {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            return Optional.ofNullable(Objects.isNull(authentication) ? null : authentication.getName());
        };
    }
```

to:

```
    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> auditorProvider() {
        return () -> {
            Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
            if (Objects.isNull(authentication) || !authentication.isAuthenticated() || !(authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof Principal)) {
                return Optional.of("anonymous");
            }
            return Optional.of(authentication.getName());
        };
    }
```

which also populate created_by in test phase where there is no security context.